# Is it possible to exchange Polish Zloty for Bitcoin with CoinFloor Exchange?

Tags: trade

[CoinFloor](https://www.coinfloor.co.uk) is an exchange that accepts deposits and withdrawals of fiat currencies EUR, GBP, USD and PLN. One can trade EUR, GBP and USD for bitcoin, but not PLN.

In fact it doesn't seem possible to trade PLN for anything, not even other fiats. Of course, it doesn't make much sense for them to accept PLN if you can't do anything with it, so I could be mistaken. If I deposit PLN, is it possible to trade it? How can this be done this?